# why i am getting a '?' mark at the end of the link after using useHistory().push('/')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I am trying to jump to another link when submitting a form. That's why I am using useHistory(). But whenever I'm submitting the form it's taking me to the link  but I'm getting a '?' mark at the end. So when I'm deploying this in netlify I'm getting 'PAGE NOT FOUND' because it doesn't match the link as I don't have a question mark at the end of my link. So how can I remove the '?' mark after the nav link?

Heres my code:

```
    const history = useHistory();
  function handleSubmit() {
    history.push("/Products");
  }
 <Form inline>
        <FormControl
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search"
          className="mr-xs-2 p-2"
        />
        <Button variant="secondary" type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          <span style={{ color: "Tomato" }}>
            <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </span>
        </Button>
      </Form>
 <Route path="/Products" exact component={SearchResults} />
```

[image: you can see the ? mark at the end of the link]

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a submit button will submit a form, which causes the browser to navigate to a new URL.

Your `handleSubmit` function is calling `history.push` to simulate *additional* navigation on top of that.

If you want to stop the form submission from navigating (because you are handing the submit button with JS) then you need to do so **explicitly**:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.push("/Products");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ? after an url stands for the parameters of the request. you can have url-encoded queries like '?firstparam=12&secondparam=hi' with firstparam= name of an input in your form.

since your form is empty (i guess) the params are empty, but the question mark gets inserted..